# Android retrofit 2 post raw json with dynamic headers

Tags: android, json, header, retrofit2

I'm Trying to Post raw JSON using Retrofit 2 with dynamic headers in Android request contains few headers which are below and code that I have tried but I am not able to understand what goes wrong.

**Headers**

```
Accept:text/csv
x-api-key:{{api_key}}
x-session-key:{{session_token}}
x-location:-10,10
x-version:1.0
x-client-id:15
Content-Type:application/json
```

**raw JSON that I want to post**

```
 {
    "commands":[
        {
                "command":"check_in",
                "sale_content_id": 1,
                "event_id": 3,
                "value": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**below is my code**

```
@Headers({"Accept: text/csv", "Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST(CHECKIN_DATA_SCANNER)
Call<CheckIn> sendCheckinDataRequest(@Body JSONObject locationPost);
```

**How I make a retrofit call in my activity class**

```
private void sendCheckinDataRequest() {

        String mSessionToken = mContext.getSessionToken();
        String mAPIkey = "staging_api_key";
        String mClientId = "15";

        RestInterface service = CheckInServiceGenerator.createService(RestInterface.class, mSessionToken, mAPIkey, mClientId);
        Call<CheckIn> call = service.sendCheckinDataRequest(mRawJson);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CheckIn>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CheckIn> call, Response<CheckIn> response) {

                Log.e(TAG, "POST RESPONSE : " + new Gson().toJson(response));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CheckIn> call, Throwable t) {
                // something went completely south (like no internet connection)

                Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

I'm getting 400 bad requests error.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways you can tackle this. Let me show you some

**1. Using HeaderMap**
Retrofit actually has a way to send an arbitrary number of headers. This can be achieved with `@HeaderMap` .

```
@Headers({"Accept: text/csv", "Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST(CHECKIN_DATA_SCANNER)
Call<CheckIn> sendCheckinDataRequest(
         @Body JSONObject locationPost, 
         @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers);
```

Which can be called like:

```
 Map<String, String> headers = HashMap<>();
 // Populate map with headers
 service.sendCheckinDataRequest(mRawJson, headers);
```

**2. Using single parameters**
If you only have a couple of dynamic headers, then you can simply use normal parameters:

```
@Headers({"Accept: text/csv", "Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST(CHECKIN_DATA_SCANNER)
Call<CheckIn> sendCheckinDataRequest(
         @Body JSONObject locationPost, 
         @Header("x-api-key") String apiKey,
         @Header("x-session-key") String sessionKey);
```

Can be called like:

```
 service.sendCheckinDataRequest(mRawJson, apiKey, sessionKey);
```

**3. Using interceptors**
If you want these headers for all requests, then perhaps the easiest is to use an interceptor:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();  
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
  @Override
  public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();

    Request request = original.newBuilder()
        .header("x-api-key", <apiKey>)
        .header("x-session-key", <sessionKey>)
        .method(original.method(), original.body())
        .build();

    return chain.proceed(request);
  }
}
```

Use this `okhttp` client with your Retrofit and every request will have the headers added.